# How to unstructure a text string that has characters and convert it to an object

Tags: java

I have a text string that I receive from PL/SQL. I need to convert each object that is separated by a ';'.
This is my string [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEqVQ.png)
I need to get that information and create the objects that come in that string.

```
//all objects come in a single text string

first object is 830114921-1<,>TIGO<,>13<,>RECARGA CELULAR TIGO;
second object is 800153993-7<,>PROTOCOLO CLARO<,>426<,>PAQUECLARO 24HRS;
third object is   800153993-7<,>PROTOCOLO CLARO<,>7<,>PINES 2000;
fourth object is  900102005-1<,>GLOBAL TV TELECOMUNICACIONES<,>92<,>JOHATRUJILLO;
```

```
Example:
Class MyClass{

Integer number;
String text;
Integer number2;
String text;
} 
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myClass.SetNumber(830114921-1);
myClass.SetText("TIGO");
myClass.SetNumber2(13);
myClass.SetText2("RECARGA CELULAR TIGO");
myList.add(myClass);
```

```
//I can split the 4 objects but if more objects come in the text string, can //no longer be. 
   String str = "830114921-1<,>TIGO<,>13<,>RECARGA CELULAR TIGO;"
                    + " 800153993-7<,>PROTOCOLO CLARO<,>426<,>PAQUECLARO 24HRS; "
                    + "800153993-7<,>PROTOCOLO CLARO<,>7<,>PINES 2000; "
                    + "900102005-1<,>GLOBAL TV TELECOMUNICACIONES<,>92<,>JOHATRUJILLO;";
           String[] arrOfStr = str.split(";", 4);
             List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
             for (String a : arrOfStr) {             
                 list.add(a);
             }
             
             for (String data : list) {
                 
                String result2 = data.replaceAll("\\<,>", " ");
                 
                  System.out.println(result2);
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count how many `;` exits in the String and then use `str.split()`

```
...

int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == ';') {
        count++;
    }
}
String[] arrOfStr = str.split(";", count);// instead of 4
...
```

This will solve you problem but there are better ways to do it, using a regular expression . Learn more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/)

### Edit :

You also need to do the same thing to every attribute of your object but the counting is a little bit different :

```
...

count = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < arrOfStr[0].length()-1; i++) {
   if (arrOfStr.charAt(i-1) == '<'arrOfStr.charAt(i) == ',' && arrOfStr.charAt(i+1) == '>') {
    count++;
   }
}

List<String> listOfObjectsFromSQL = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
String[] attributes = new String[count];

  for (String strObj : arrOfStr) {
      attributes = strObj.split("<,>", count);
      //create you object
      MyClass obj = new MyClass();

      //fill your object with values from the query 
      obj.setNumber(attributes[0]);
      obj.setText(attributes[1]);
      obj.setNumber2(attributes[2]);
      obj.setText2(attributes[3]);

      //add them to your list to use them...
      listOfObjectsFromSQL.add(obj);
  }

 ...
```

Comment: yes this works but after splitting the objects I need to add the list of each object I still can't get it.

Comment: @alexis did it work ?

Comment: This is working properly thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The data is split with `<,>` and `;` so you should easily be able to split the string and collect the data. Java has a `String.split()` method. First split the string object that contains all the data into an array of strings by splitting on `;` and then loop over these and split them on `<,>`.

At this point you should be able to set your attributes according to the order of the data in the string (assuming these are ordered properly).

Comment: I've been doing that but in the text string there can be several objects, when I get to the ; I need to add each object with its properties in a list

Comment: If you split on `;`, it will yield an array of strings that each include a row of data. Now it's up to you to for loop that array and split the string again on `<,>`. This second split within the loop will yield each field of each row of data. 
At this point, all you have to do is assign each field to each instance of `MyClass` and save these objects in a list.

Comment: I have updated the publication and added what I have achieved but I am still stuck.